# Axler exercise 1.11

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

I am trying to solve this exericse in Axler's text.

> Explain why there does not exist $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that 
>   $$\lambda (2 - 3i, 5 + 4i, -6 + 7i) = (12 - 5i, 7 + 22i, -32 - 9i).$$

This isn't particularly difficult, but my solution seems far too simple. I assume I've made a mistake somewhere.

**Solution.** Assume, seeking a contradiction, that there exists such a $\lambda$. Scaling the first element by $\lambda$, we have
$$(2\lambda - 3\lambda i, 5\lambda + 4\lambda i, -6\lambda + 7\lambda i) = (12 - 5i, 7 + 22i, -32 - 9i).$$
Elements in $\mathbb{C}^4$ are equal if and only if their corresponding entries are equal. Focusing on the first component, we have
$$2\lambda - 3\lambda i = 12 - 5i.$$
Elements in $\mathbb{C}$ are equal if and only if their real and imaginary components are equal. Hence, 
$$2\lambda = 12, \; -3\lambda = -5.$$
The first equality implies that $\lambda = 6$. Plugging into the second equality gives 
$$-18 = -5,$$
which is absurd. Hence, no such $\lambda$ exists.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: That's exactly what you are supposed to do

Comment: I realized after writing this, though, that $\lambda$ is an element of $\mathbb{C}$, not $\mathbb{R}$. Does that complicate things? For example, I equate real and imaginary components treating $\lambda$ as a real. I feel as though there must be a counterexample to what I've done.

Comment: Sorry I didn't check carefully, I'd assumed you did the rest right when you equate the coordinates. The answer below is correct, you can't compare $2\lambda = 12$ for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because $\lambda$ is **complex**, so in $2\lambda-3\lambda i = 12- 5i$ we cannot compare real and complex parts!

Just divide: $$\lambda = \frac{12-5i}{2-3i}$$ from the first coordinates.

Can you compute $\lambda$?

Or alternatively: from the second coordinate comparison

$$\lambda= \frac{7+22i}{5+4i}$$ and we might derive a contradiction from

$$\frac{7+22i}{5+4i} = \frac{12-5i}{2-3i}$$ from cross-multiplying:

Is $$(7+22i)(2-3i) = (2-5i)(5+4i) ?$$

If not, we have a contradiction too.

Comment: This is what I thought about a minute after writing this. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnP. Just do as you would for $\Bbb R$. Admittedly, division is a bit more complicated, but I suggested a way with using cross-multiplications, which involves fewer computations.